# What does orthogonal mean in matrix theory?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, mathematical-modeling

I know orthogonal involves right angles. However, in matrix theory,the concept still  doesn't make sense to me. I was given a definition  that vectors $x_1,...,x_k$ 
which belong to $\mathbb{C}^n$ form an orthogonal set if $x_i^* x_j=0$ for all pairs, $1\leq i<j\leq k$.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out: in $\Bbb C^n$, defining the orthogonality of vectors in terms of the angle between them is not exactly the "correct" thing to do.

To start, let's talk about the situation in $\Bbb R^n$. Note that the way we measure angles between two vectors $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$ is by looking at the dot-product $x^Ty$.  More specifically, we can say that 
$$
x^Ty = \|x\| \cdot \|y\| \cdot \cos \theta.
$$
If $x$ and $y$ are non-zero, then they will be perpendicular (i.e. orthogonal) iff (if and only if) $\theta = 90^\circ$, which happens iff $\cos \theta = 0$, which happens iff $x^Ty = 0$.

With that in mind, it is convenient to say that in $\Bbb R^n$, two vectors are **defined** to be orthogonal when their dot-product $x^Ty = 0$. The natural generalization of this definition is to say that two vectors in $\Bbb C^n$ are orthogonal if and only if their "dot-product" $x^*y$ is equal to zero.

Interestingly, it is no longer the case in $\Bbb C^n$ that non-zero vectors are orthogonal iff the angle between them is $90^\circ$.

Comment: I didnt know that about $\mathbb{C}^n$ having orthogonal vectors that arent 90 degrees apart. Although its hard to visualize angles in a complex hyperspace.  Is there a special name given to vectors, orthogonal or not, which *are* 90 degrees apart?

Comment: @SquishyRhode not one that I know of.  If you want to play with the idea, note that the angle between complex vectors (where we interpret the real and imaginary parts as belonging to orthogonal axes for geometric purposes) satisfies
$$
\operatorname{Re}[x^*y] = \|x\|\,\|y\| \cos \theta.
$$
As an extreme case, note that $x$ and $ix$ cannot be orthogonal since they fail to be linearly independent, but the angle between them (in the above sense) is $90^\circ$.

Comment: @SquishyRhode actually, a quick correction to your statement: with my definition of an angle, it **is** in fact true that orthogonal vectors have a $90^\circ$ angle between them.  It is the converse, i.e. that vectors with a $90^\circ$ angle between them must be orthogonal, that fails to hold.

Comment: A note: a neat justification for this definition of a complex angle is the law of cosines.  In particular: for vectors $u,v$, we have
$$
\|u^2\| + \|v^2\| - 2 \operatorname{Re} \langle u,v \rangle 
= \|u - v\|^2 \overset{!}{=} \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2 - 2 \|u\| \|v\| \cos \theta
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is really just the "nicest" way to extend the definition of orthogonal in real spaces to complex spaces. Note that in real vector spaces, $x\cdot y=\vert x\vert\vert y\vert \cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $x$ and $y$. So as you say, if the angle between them is a right angle, then $\cos(\theta)=0$, so $x\cdot y=0$, and the vectors are orthogonal. Now also clearly for real vectors in a complex vector space, when we complex-conjugated the first vector, it doesn't change it, and so the same angle based orthogonality definition holds. But we can now also tell if a pair of complex vectors are "orthogonal", where it isn't so intuitively clear what orthogonal should mean (what is the angle between a pair of complex vectors?).

There are good reasons for conjugating the first argument, but I think the most intuitive one is that it means that the inner product of a vector with itself is always the square of its magnitude (because we know intuitively what the magnitude of a complex vector should be), so this property gets carried over from the dot product in real vector spaces.

Comment: There are good reasons for conjugating *one* of the arguments, but there is not a good reason it has to be the first argument. It could also be the second argument. Physicists tend to conjugate the first argument while mathematicians tend to conjugate the second argument.

Comment: Yes, that's a point, but it's pretty clear that either definition leads to the same results, and you have to choose one of them; much like choosing $i$ or $-i$, or the handedness of the cross product, as a couple of examples.